# Classifying the ul tag

Tags: html, css

I want to use such a structure in my WordPress site:

HTML:

```html
<div class="main_txt">

<ul>
    <li>
       <h2>text 1</h2>
    </li>

    <li>
        <h2>text 2</h2>
    </li>

    <li>
        <h2>text 3</h2>
    </li>

    <li>
        <h2>text 4</h2>
    </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Call and style the ul li tags as follows:

```css
 .main_txt ul li h2{
        color: #c00579;
    }

    .main_txt ul li > li h2{
        color: #ff0000;
    }

    .main_txt ul li > li > li h2{
        color: #1eff00;
    }

    .main_txt ul li > li > li > li h2{
        color: #1900ff;
    }
```

But only the first style is executed and the other styles have no effect.

Is there a way to style ul li tags without giving a class?

Comment: The other styles have no effect because their selectors do no match. The second one matches all `h2` elements that are descendants of `li` elements that are direct children of other `li` elements. And there are no such elements in the HTML.

Comment: BTW, an `li` cannot be the direct child of another `li`; it must be the child of another element, like a `ul` or `ol`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.main_txt ul li h2 {}` selects all the `h2` elements in all the `li`'s.

`.main_txt ul li > li h2{` selects all the `h2` elements in all the `li`'s in all the `li`'s.

`.main_txt ul li > li > li h2{` selects all the `h2` elements in all the `li`'s in all the `li`'s in all the `li`'s.

And so on. You aren't really selecting the first, second, or third `h2`. If that's what you need to do, you can use `:nth_child`. For example:

`.main_txt ul li:nth-child(2) h2{` selects the `h2` in the second `li`.